# Excel 2010: Need to copy certain cells to different worksheet based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet in Excel 2010, that I am wanting to take certain cells in a row and copy them to another worksheet when a certain value is entered into a specific cell in the same row.

For example: In Worksheet A, in cell A2, if a "X" is entered, I want cell A5, A7 and A13-17 to be copied to Worksheet B. In Worksheet B, they should be copied to the next available row, but I need them copied to specific cells (not the same as in Worksheet A- i.e: cell A5 would need to copy to cell 2 in Worksheet B; A7 to cell 4 and A13-17 to 10-14). And the cells they would be copied to in Worksheet B would also need to be created in a new row.

I have some VBA that does something similar; however, it copies the entire row. For the above, I need only specific cells AND they won't match same cells in Worksheet B.

Here is what I have been able to get to work (to copy entire row):

```
Sub Testing_Issue(ByVal Target As Range)
  'Disable events so code doesn't re-fire when row is deleted
    Application.EnableEvents = False
  'Was the change made to Column T?
    If Target.Column = 20 Then
  'If yes, does the Target read "Y"?
    If Target = "Y" Then
  'If Y, determine next empty row in Sheet "TEST"
    nxtRw = Sheets("TEST").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  'Copy the row from the Open worksheet and move to the TEST worksheet
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("A" & nxtRw)
    Else
      MsgBox ("That is not a valid entry")
    End If
  End If
'Re-enable Events
   Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

I tried using the following instead of the entire row part, but does not work.

```
Target.Range("A13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("A5 & nxtRw")
Target.Range("B13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("C5 & nxtRw")
Target.Range("I13:J13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("E5 & nxtRw")
```

I would greatly appreciate some advice, as I really need to get this working right. Please let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want copied and where you want it pasted to, but hopefully this will get you started in the right direction:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCheck As Range
    Dim CheckCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set rngCheck = Intersect(Me.Columns("T"), Target)

    If Not rngCheck Is Nothing Then
        For Each CheckCell In rngCheck.Cells
            If CheckCell.Value = "Y" Then
                With Sheets("TEST")
                    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Me.Cells(CheckCell.Row, "A").Copy Destination:=.Cells(lRow, "A")
                    Me.Cells(CheckCell.Row, "C").Copy Destination:=.Cells(lRow, "B")
                    Me.Cells(CheckCell.Row, "I").Copy Destination:=.Cells(lRow, "E")
                    Me.Cells(CheckCell.Row, "J").Copy Destination:=.Cells(lRow, "F")
                End With
            End If
        Next CheckCell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: tigeravatar - Thanks! this worked perfect...i've been banging my head against the keyboard trying to get this to work for awhile and had not been able to get any help on other sites. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub tester(rng As Range)
Dim rwSrc As Range, rwDest As Range

    Set rwSrc = rng.Cells(1).EntireRow

    If UCase(rwSrc.Cells(2).Value) = "X" Then
        Set rwDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B").Cells( _
            Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

        rwSrc.Cells(5).Copy rwDest.Cells(2)
        rwSrc.Cells(7).Copy rwDest.Cells(4)
        rwSrc.Cells(13).Resize(1, 5).Copy rwDest.Cells(10)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Target.Range("A13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("A5" & nxtRw)
Target.Range("B13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("C5" & nxtRw)
Target.Range("I13:J13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("E5" & nxtRw)
```